# I guess this one is for the old ones out there

Tags: riddle

What am I?

```
I am not the trimmings of a bush,
but something closer to a mush.
I am not the clams in your hand,
but that guess I understand.

As long as you  answer with aplomb,
The answer you will not be far from.
Admittedly my humor is a little dried,
But much of my moral fiber is supplied.

As for your guesses throw the worst away,
The answer is evident if I may say.
```

Hint:

> It is all of these things. But for the answer I am just aiming for one of them.

If anyone is wondering what the original riddle was, and maybe tell me if you think it was particularly solvable back then:

> What am I? 
> I am not the trimmings of a bush, 
> but something closer to a mush. 
> I am not the clams in your hand, 
> but that guess I understand. 
> As for your guess throw the worst away,
> The answer is evident if I may say.

Comment: Would "I am not worth a dollar." be a valid clue? If so, I've got a vague idea of what the riddle is pointing to.

Comment: So I would not personally use that as a clue but I could see that in fact being a valid statement, I am thinking of adding a line or two due to a potention unclarity(?) in the riddle

Comment: A hint or two perhaps?

Comment: Added more, and the title is a hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> a prune!

```
I am not the trimmings of a bush,
```

> Another word for trimming a bush is pruning.

```
but something closer to a mush.
```

> Prunes are closer to mush than to branches.

```
I am not the clams in your hand,
but that guess I understand.
```

> When you've soaked in water for a while some people call the wrinkles in your hands prunes.

```
As long as you  answer with aplomb,
The answer you will not be far from.
```

> Aplomb sounds like "A plum" which is close to a prune.

```
Admittedly my humor is a little dried,
But much of my moral fiber is supplied.
```

> A prune is a dried plum, but still has all the fiber of a plum.

The title:

> Older folks have more wrinkles (prunes) and may require a little bit of prune juice to stay regular.

Comment: Hahahah answer with 'aplomb', I love it.

Comment: Well done. @BaileyM that line rather amused me.